# RSpec Test Suite Not Running After Rails 5.0.1 Upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

We're upgrading a Rails application from 3.2 to 5.0. We got to 4.2 and had a test suite passing 100%, we're now at 5.0.1 and the test-suite is throwing an argument error.

When running rake spec:models, the following error occurs:

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __dir__)

ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
```

**Ruby V 2.5.1**
**RSpec V 3.8**

Running rake db:migrate task in development environment completes, however..

After running db:migrate in test environment, the following error(s) occur:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
/home/vagrant/rtest/config/initializers/load_rtest_config.rb:5:in `test'
/home/vagrant/rtest/config/initializers/load_rtest_config.rb:5:in `<top 
(required)>'
/home/vagrant/rtest/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/rtest/bin/rails:4:in `require'
/home/vagrant/rtest/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**envrionment.rb:**

```
# Load the rails application
# require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__) # RAILS 4.2
require_relative 'application'


# Initialize the rails application
# Changes for rtest upgrade
Rails.application.initialize!
```

**load_rtest_config.rb:**

```
require 'ostruct'
require 'yaml'

config = OpenStruct.new(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/rtest.yml"))
::RTestConfig = OpenStruct.new(config.send(Rails.env))

::SummaryConfig = OpenStruct.new(YAML.load_file("# 
{Rails.root}/config/summary.yml"))

::LDAPConfig = OpenStruct.new(YAML.load_file("# 
{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"))
```

**Relevant gems:**

```
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'

group :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', :require => false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'rspec-its'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'

  #Rails 5 Upgrade
  # gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
# require 'spork'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'rspec/its'

# ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
# ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!


require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __dir__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_bot_rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'authlogic/test_case'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}


  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.expose_current_running_example_as :example
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
    config.include Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model
    config.include Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model
    config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.include LoginMacros, :type => :controller
    config.include LoginMacrosRequest, :type => :request
    config.after(:each) { Warden.test_reset! }
    end

  puts "Reloading controllers and models"
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/controllers//*.rb"].each do |controller|
    load controller
  end
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models//*.rb"].each do |model|
    load model
  end
  puts "Done"

  FactoryBot.reload
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each do |f|
    require f
  end
```

**edit:** Apologies if the question isn't clear, this is my first question, thanks.

Comment: The stack trace should tell you which line in `rails_helper.rb` raises the error. But there is quite a lot of cruft in there. Do you really need to reload the models? And you should not use `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` if you are not using ActiveRecord::Fixtures.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the reply.

 The issue is on line 9 in rails_helper
`require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __dir__)` each time the spec.rb files call it, it returns ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3) and ends with: Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The problem was here:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
/home/vagrant/rtest/config/initializers/load_rtest_config.rb:5:in `test'
```

The word 'test' was causing rubymine to think it was a method test (no idea where it's defined) which required 2..3 arguments.

**load_rtest_config**:

```
config = OpenStruct.new(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/rtest.yml"))
::RTestConfig = OpenStruct.new(config.send(Rails.env))
```

The .send method above was not passing the string "test" through correctly. It however would pass "development" through.

**FIX:**

::RTestConfig = OpenStruct.new(config[Rails.env])